# Use unauthorized argument names in a function

Tags: python, python-3.x, elasticsearch

I'm using the python's library [elasticsearch](https://elasticsearch-py.readthedocs.io/en/7.10.0/api.html) and try to use the client for this kind of request:

```
GET /_search?size=250&from=250
```

My question is more about *python* than *elasticsearch*: how to specify the argument **from** ? The name is already use by python as a *keyword* and when I run the next function:

```
 def request(size_hits=10, from_hit=0):
       host = 'XXXX'
       YOUR_ACCESS_KEY = 'XXXX'
       YOUR_SECRET_KEY = 'XXXX'
       REGION = 'XXXX' #change to your region
       awsauth = AWS4Auth(YOUR_ACCESS_KEY, YOUR_SECRET_KEY, REGION, 'es')

       es = Elasticsearch(
           hosts=[{'host': host, 'port': XXXX}],
           http_auth=awsauth,
           use_ssl=True,
           verify_certs=True,
           connection_class=RequestsHttpConnection
       )
       
       res = es.search(index='index_name', from=from_hit, size=size_hits, body={"query": {"match_all": {}}})
       print(res)
```

I got an error:

```
File "test_elasticsearch.py", line 24
      res = es.search(index="agence_test2", from=from_hits, size=n_hits, body={"query": {"match_all": {}}})
                                            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

[Extract of documentation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hHyFZ.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the very top of the page you've linked to, you can find this:

> for compatibility with the Python ecosystem we use from_ instead of from and doc_type instead of type as parameter names.